# Postgresql get single column of row in for loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This is probably really easy, but its driving me crazy.

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_group(serverid BIGINT, name VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    group server_groups%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR group IN SELECT * FROM server_groups WHERE server_id = serverid AND LOWER(group_name) = LOWER(name) LOOP
        RETURN group.id;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 0;
END;
$$;
```

And the following tables:
**server**

```
server_id |  server_name
----------+---------------
 3251623  |  ServerOfDoom
 5578921  |  BestServerEU
```

**server_groups**

```
id | server_id |  group_name
---+----------+---------------
 1 |  3251623  |  aNiceGroup
 2 |  5578921  |  Valorant
 3 |  5578921  |  Admins
```

But when executing my function query I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 8:         RETURN group.id;
```

I get that this means I can't just get the `id` of the `group` row by saying `group.id`, but I'm really going crazy finding out how after visiting 100 different sites (maybe I'm just a bad Googler) 
How do I get a single attribute of a row in a for loop?

Comment: Your function is declared to return a **single** value, yet the use of a loop seems to imply you want to return multiple values (=rows). What exactly do you want the function to do?

Comment: `group` is a reserved keyword. Give your variable a different name and it should work (although you'll get the next error later, because your function can only return a single scalar value, not multiple values)

Comment: I basically want to return either the id of the group found (there can only be one) or 0. If I remove the Declare block i get the error `loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables || LINE 5: FOR group < ...`

Comment: Well, the loop would (try to) return **all** rows found. You can't remove the `declare` block if you want to use a variable in PL/pgSQL

Comment: Well anyway the point is my for loop only has the length 1 or 0 so that shouldnt be the problem, my problem is that I'm unable to get the id of my row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. Your requirement can be achieved with a single SQL query (which can be wrapped in a SQL function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_group(serverid BIGINT, name VARCHAR(100)) 
  RETURNS BIGINT
as
$$
  select coalesce(max(id), 0) as id
  from server_groups 
  where server_id = serverid 
    and lower(group_name) = lower(name);
$$
language sql
stable;
```

If the WHERE clause returns no match, `max(id)` will yield `null` and the `coalesce()` will turn that into a 0 (although I would think a `null` would make much more sense).

If the WHERE clauses matches a row, the query will return the highest ID. As you only expect a single row from the query, the aggregate function won't change that.

---

If you really want that to be a PL/pgSQL function, you can use the `FOUND` status [as shown in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_group(serverid BIGINT, name VARCHAR(100)) 
  RETURNS BIGINT
AS $$
declare
  group_id int;
BEGIN
  select id
    into group_id
  from server_groups 
  where server_id = serverid 
  and lower(group_name) = lower(name);
  
  if found then
    return group_id;
  else 
    return 0;
  end if;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```